# @RequestParam not mapping entire string

Tags: java, spring-boot, url, servlet-3.0, http-request-parameters

I have a Get endpoint that accepts a query string as request param . The issue with the endpoint it that the request param string can contain characters like ?,/ etc which is causing issues.Is there any way to map a string which contains ?,/ etc to a variable in a rest controller ?

Have already tried using @PathVariable instead of using @RequestParam but it is still not reading the value correctly.
When using @PathVariable to map the uri , the ? is getting omitted.
When using @RequestParam, it is throwing an Exception.Stacktrace is provided.

```
@GetMapping("/getResult")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> getData(@RequestParam(value="text") String text) {
    //Call to service layer passing text as a param
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("GET Response", HttpStatus.OK);
}

URL : 'localhost/getResult?text=How you doing?'
```

Stacktrace:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method
>   name. HTTP method names must be tokens  Error parsing HTTP request
>   header Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be
>   logged at DEBUG level.
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method
>   name. HTTP method names must be tokens at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:422)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14] at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:683)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14] at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14] at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14] at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14] at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_05] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_05] at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14] at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]

For the expected result , i would like to map the string "How you doing?" to a path variable or query param variable with the entire string intact, instead of the '?' getting omitted.

Comment: You need to encode the string before you send it to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encode the `question mark(?)` as `%3F` and you're good to go.

There's no other way you can send question mark in query as it is a **special character**.

Comment: Yes, but make sure you only encode the parameters, not the entire URL!

Comment: %3F is a representation of question mark, I hope you understand that. Each special character needs to be encoded. Look here: https://secure.n-able.com/webhelp/NC_9-1-0_SO_en/Content/SA_docs/API_Level_Integration/API_Integration_URLEncoding.html

Comment: Also, you should use a library for encoding strings and not handle that yourself.

Comment: Got it , thank you.Slipped my mind that the query params had to be encoded since i was using postman to hit the endpoint and not through ajax.

Answer (score 4):

If you are calling the url direct from browser or curl or postman. you should use  encoding for different special characters like for space encoding is %20. That means when you write **"how are you?"** this would be ***"how%20are%20you%3F"*** in the url. Please refer to this [site](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for more understanding.

And If the call is from any programming language. please use URL encoders.

Answer (score 3):

Providing a Java solution:
You can use the `URLEncoder` to achieve what you want:

```
URLEncoder enc = new URLEncoder();
enc.encode(String toEncode, String charset)
```

There is also a method that accepts only the string to be encoded, but this one is deprecated.

If you are calling from a Javascript client, you can use `encodeURIComponent()`  :

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the parameters with special characters in the URL. You can use `encodeURIComponent` from front end .

If you are using postman, you need to set following in Pre-request scripts,

```
var encoded = encodeURIComponent(postman.getEnvironmentVariable("text"));
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("encoded text", encoded);
```